# Can I solve this differential equation at a point?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential

I want to solve this differential equation evaluted at $x=0$. I will start with an example with $m=2$

$$
f(0)+f'(0)+f''(0)=2\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}+4
$$
where $m$,$\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{1}$ are positive constants. The $f(x)$ that satisfies the previous equation is

$$
\prod_{k=1}^{2}\left(\lambda_{k}.x+2(1-\lambda_{k})\right)
$$

I have encountered with this equation while solving an integral. The result was

$$
\left. \sum_{n=0}^{m+1} \left( \frac{d^n}{d x^n}\left( x^{m-1}\prod_{k=1}^{2}\left(\lambda_{k}.x+m(1-\lambda_{k})\right)\right)\right)\right|_{x=0}=m\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}+m^2
$$

So I want to find f(x) that satisfies

$$
\left. \sum_{n=0}^{m+1} \left( \frac{d^n}{d x^n}\left( f(x) \right)\right)\right|_{x=0}=m_{1}\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}+m_{1}m_{2}
$$

Note: $m_{1}\neq m_{2}$.

Comment: That 's not really an ODE, basically any $f(x)=a+bx+c\,\dfrac{x^2}2+x^3g(x)$ with $a+b+c=m\lambda_1\lambda_2+m^2$ and $g$ without pole in zero would fit. Of course you are not limited to that, but that the point, the problem is not very restrictive...

Comment: @zwim I will modify my question to clearify my point.

Comment: There is a typo mistake in my equation.

Comment: This is not an ODE.

Comment: @xpaul I don't know much in ODE, but I have encountered with this while doing an integration. I have edited my post, can you please have a look?