# I want to find the function $f(x)$ that satisfies the equation.

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have encountered with this equation while solving an integral. The integral result was

$$
\left. \sum_{n=0}^{m+1} \left( \frac{d^n}{d x^n}\left( x^{m-1}\prod_{k=1}^{2}\left(\lambda_{k}.x+m(1-\lambda_{k})\right)\right)\right)\right|_{x=0}=m\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}+m^2
$$

where $m$,$\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{1}$ are positive constants.
Now suppose I have $m_1$ and $m_2$, then I have

$$
\left. \sum_{n=0}^{N} \left( \frac{d^n}{d x^n}\left( f(x) \right)\right)\right|_{x=0}=m_{1}\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}+m_{1}m_{2}
$$

What is the value of $N$ and function $f(x)$ that satisfies the previous equation. Or what should we modify on the first equation to meet the last one.

Note: $m_{1}\neq m_{2}$.

Comment: In the first equation,  $m$ appears in both a summation index and the right hand side, hence linking the expressions. By replacing the summation index with an apparently-independent $N$, you break the link and trivialize the problem. After all, it appears that we can take $N=0$ and $f(x) =  m_1\lambda_1\lambda_2+m_1 m_2$. or, say, take $N$ to be arbitrary, and let $f(x) = \frac{1}{N+1} ( m_1\lambda_1\lambda_2+m_1 m_2) e^x$.

Comment: @Blue let's consider $N=m_{2}+1$

Comment: *"let's consider $N=m_2+1$."* ...  That doesn't de-trivialize the problem; both of my examples still work. (The $N=0$ condition for $f(x)=m_1\lambda_1\lambda_2+m_1m_2$ wasn't necessary; any $N$ will do, since the $n$-th order derivatives for $n>0$ vanish.) Besides, the consideration seems pretty arbitrary. ... Perhaps you could say something about what you're trying to accomplish in generalizing the original relation.

Comment: I just noticed that this question asks the same thing as [your previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3874185/409), merely trading "$m+1$" for "$N$" (or "$m_2+1$", according to your earlier comment) as the upper summation index. If you're trying to attract attention to the problem, reposting it is not the appropriate way. (This only adds to clutter and confusion to the site.) Instead, edit the original question to improve its quality, or (once you have enough reputation) [offer a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065). ... Voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Blue ok,thanks.